# can esi:include src be used as an esi variable in html page

Tags: html, akamai, esi

Example:

Issue with esi:assign and esi:include in a html page rendered through akamai cdn

```
http://www.trial.com/abc/def/ghjiy (Akamai rendering src) has content "abc"

In an html page
<esi:include src="http://www.trial.com/abc/def/ghjiy"></esi:include> will return "abc"
can I assign this to a variable so we can use it multiple times in the html  page using 
<esi:vars>$(val)</esi:vars>

I have tried something like this 
<esi:text><esi:assign name="val">'</esi:text><esi:include 
src="http://www.trial.com/abc/def/ghjiy"></esi:include><esi:text>'</esi:assign></esi:text>"

But after html page being rendered the <esi:assign> tags has not been parsed and returned 
the following in page source
<esi:assign name="val">abc</esi:assign>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the web performance folks visit here - can you go to the Akamai community at http://community.akamai.com and visit the web performance section?  You should get a timely response there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `esi:eval` instead of `esi:include`.

This http://www.trial.com/abc/def/ghjiy
could return esi code fragment which will be evaluated at the edge. For example:
   `<esi assign name="val">I assign this to a variable so we can use it multiple times in the html  page using</esi:assign>`

And then later you can use
   `<esi:vars>$(val)</esi:vars>`